# View of organic groups name list with no activity

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I'm running a Drupal 7 site, and I want to create a list view of group names with no activity within last 60 days. For example if user have not created any content with in those groups.

Currently groups (OG) hold different content-types/nodes i.e news, galleries, wikis, and discussions.

Can someone please help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a custom table with group id and access timestamp. Whenever you are adding a new content to OG, update the table with group id and current timestamp. Then list inactive groups (by calculating current time from your timestamp saved in table), using [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) function.